# How can I replace a string with this rules?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string that can contain any kind of char. I want to:

1. Replace the accent char with non-accent char (like à must become a, é=>e, and so on);
2. Keep in the string only a-zA-Z, numbers and `-`;

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you want to happen to characters which aren't a-z, A-Z, numbers, - or accented letters?

Comment: they must be deleted from the string :)

Comment: @markzzz: so what e'=>e means ? Is this not replacement?

Comment: yes, replacement for accent letter, which became in the scope of a-zA-Z

Comment: possible duplicate of [How remove accents in PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836670/how-remove-accents-in-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
// Remove all accents
var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("Cyrillic").GetBytes(text);
text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

// Remove all unwanted characters
var regex = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9-]");
text = regex.Replace(text, "");
```

Comment: What is the role of `GetEncoding("Cyrillic")` ? There is no accent chars in cyrillic.

Comment: Yeah in fact, I also don't understand why it works. Also with Ӓ?

Comment: I don't think this code will *substitude* `e'` with `e`, cause that is actually OP's asking for...

Comment: In fact, it do it (with `è`) :O

Comment: I expect there are potential input characters for which [`Encoding.GetBytes(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx) will throw a `EncoderFallbackException. Or rather how could you ever be sure it won't?

Comment: Why is this replacing a valid string with no accent to all question marks?

Comment: Because this answer could *never* work for Cyrillic. It was probably tested using non-US text, eg Swedish or German - codepages that have *some* characters in common with US-ASCII. It *mangles* any non-US-ASCII characters and then removes them from the string

Answer (score 3):

You can try [`string.Normalize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.normalize.aspx) (to `NormalizationForm.FormD` to split accented characters into a "base" character and one or more combining characters) and then filter out all non-letter characters.

Edit:

```
string s = "éäï";
var ca = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
          .ToCharArray()
          .Where(c => c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
// ca contains eai now
```

Comment: @Richard: thank for your edit, with default normalization form this doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You can access every char in the string. U take the actual char, send it to a method. In that method you have a bunch of if -lse or a case switch. That would be your rules. If one of the rules accept your char, you return the replacement for that char.

Answer (score -1):

This function will strip out all non-allowable characters and replace your accents.

```
private string FormatStringToAllowableCharacters(string inString) {
        string returnString;
        returnString = inString.Replace("é","e");
        returnString = returnString.Replace("ä","a");
        returnString = returnString.Replace("ï","i");
    returnString = Regex.Replace(returnString, "[^a-zA-Z0-9-]", "");
        return returnString;
    }
```

Comment: This converts `""` to `"0"` which isn't part of the question. It also fails to translate `ï` to `i`.

Comment: Fixed to show just the allowable characters... Still, I don't know who you change the accented characters.  Others may have a better answer for you.

Comment: Fixed again, this time to replace the accented characters.

Comment: I think you should cover a few characters more like in [ASCIIFoldingFilter](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/lucene.net/tags/Lucene.Net_2_9_4g_RC1/src/core/Analysis/ASCIIFoldingFilter.cs?revision=1230956&view=markup) :)

Comment: L.B.  Good comment, I was ignorant on exactly how many of these characters there are!  Your link is a good one, and seems like it covers all the necessary characters.