# Convert Unicode to ASCII in .NET from MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD CAPITAL I

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, character-encoding, ascii

I have this string below that needs to be convered to ASCII.

I tried to see if it was already ASCII and it seems to be this encoding below.  Is there a way to do this in .NET?

```
The strings first character is symbol: , code point: 1d5dc, position: 1, so non ASCII, but Unicode Character 'MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD CAPITAL I' (U+1D5DC)
```

Comment: You've already asked the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64390182/encoding-getencodingcyrillic-making-all-text-question-marks-in-net)

Comment: No its different, and if I get a good answer here I can answer the one from the other if people are having issue.  I would of never guessed it was an encoding issue in the other question.

Comment: The strings in C# are unicode, you can try to convert string character by character [as bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5348852/1997232), but the proper way is to [use Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400777/1997232).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply .NET [String.Normalize Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize) using *Compatibility Decomposition*, see [Unicode normalization forms](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/).

If your string is in variable `s2` then use something like (an example from the former link):

```
s2.IsNormalized(NormalizationForm.FormKD)
```

Here's PowerShell equivalent:

```
'      '.Normalize('FormKD')
INDOOR SOFTBALL TOURNAMENT DIAMOND JAXX AND HITZ
```