# Powershell replace special characters like ü

Tags: powershell

```
(Get-Content -Path $filePath) -creplace ${find}, $replace | Add-Content -Path $tempFilePath
```

If `$find` and `$replace` contains below values it's not replacing it

```
ç c
à a
é e
```

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting Unicode string to ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658267/converting-unicode-string-to-ascii) or [Replacing characters with diacritics in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43493484/1701026)

Comment: Works for me:  `'ç' -replace 'ç','c'`

Answer (score 2):

You need to `-Encoding UTF8` to the `Get-Content` method, for reading the special characters correctly:

```
(Get-Content -Path $filePath -Encoding UTF8) -creplace ${find}, $replace | Add-Content -Path $tempFilePath
```

Answer (score 2):

If by *characters like ü* you mean [Diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) you can use this:

```
function Replace-Diacritics {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string] $Text
    )
    ($Text.Normalize([Text.NormalizationForm]::FormD).ToCharArray() | 
     Where-Object {[Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($_) -ne 
                   [Globalization.UnicodeCategory]::NonSpacingMark }) -join ''
}

# you can experiment with the `-Encoding` parameter
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\TheFile.txt' -Encoding UTF8 -Raw | Replace-Diacritics | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\TheNewFile.txt'
```