# Powershell - Replace "umlauts" in whole array

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I have got a csv with ";" delimiters which i imported with import-csv -delimiter ';'
having done that i get an array with 3 Rows (class name name2)
now the problem is: i need to remove "umlauts" from the array
I already tried it like that

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\csvfile.csv -Delimiter ';'
$csv1.name2 = $csv1.Familienname -ireplace 'ä', 'ae'
$csv1.name2
```

to no avail, the output still remains the same (i.e ä stays ä and is not replaced by ae)

another idea I had was to write a loop that replaces the umlauts but I cant wrap my head around how to do that:
 could i do it somewhat like that

```
foreach ( ä,ö,ü in $csv1.name2) 
{ replace with a,oe,ue}
```

I would already be very thankful for just some links that get me in the right direction.

Comment: It's better to replace in the source file: `(gc file.csv -raw) -replace 'ä', 'ae' | ConvertFrom-Csv`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How remove accents in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836670/how-remove-accents-in-powershell)

Comment: hi! that sounds good, can i add more umlauts to that? like (gc file.csv -raw) -replace 'ä', 'ae'; 'ö', 'oe' | ConvertFrom-Csv

Comment: You can daisy chain `-replace`, so `(gc file.csv -raw) -replace 'ä', 'ae' -replace 'ö', 'oe' | ConvertFrom-Csv -del ';'`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician thanks! but what does the -del stand for?    nvm figured it out its the alias for delimiter?

Comment: Yeah, for parameters you only have to actually use enough of it to make it unique, so since there are no other parameters that start with `-del` PowerShell assumes that it must be short for `-Delimiter`.

Comment: alright thanks to everyone if somebody has the same problem: here is the apparent solution     $csv = (gc $PSScriptRoot\csvfile.csv -raw) -ireplace 'ä', 'ae' -ireplace 'ö', 'oe' -ireplace 'ü', 'ue'  -ireplace 'ß', 'ss'       | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'                  is there something like a powershell chat where i can ask small stupid questions like that?

Comment: @vogelspinne24 post it as an answer (self-answers are perfectly fine), not a comment

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
$csv = (gc $PSScriptRoot\csvfile.csv -raw) -ireplace 'ä', 'ae' -ireplace 'ö', 'oe' -ireplace 'ü', 'ue' -ireplace 'ß', 'ss' | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'
```