# Powershell: Replace german language from CSV (UTF8)

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file that contains some column. In those columns, some characters are in  German language.

**Sample Data**

```
Test01ñ
DúSibaagh01
ËTheroË01Ë
DMrçzundaljak01
PçSchpaglawarz01ç
```

**Script**

```
import-csv D:\users.csv | 
foreach {
 If($_.Samaccountname -contains "ñ") {
 $_.Samaccountname -replace "ñ","N"
 }
 } | export-csv D:\Users_myfile.csv
```

Unfortunately, script doesn't replace **ñ**  with **N**
If condition always false.
I tried with -match and -like keyword. But none of them is working in this case.

Any advise what to do.

Comment: Those special characters `ñ   ú   Ë   ç` are definitely **NOT** German ones! More like French and Spanish ....

Comment: this looks like it answers your question ... active directory - How remove accents in PowerShell? - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836670/how-remove-accents-in-powershell

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for your help. Let me try.

Comment: @Ironic - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

`-contains` is a collection operator - it doesn't work on strings. Use [`String.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains) instead:

```
Import-Csv D:\users.csv |ForEach-Object {
    if($_.Samaccountname.Contains("ñ")) {
        $_.Samaccountname = $_.Samaccountname -replace "ñ","N"
    }
    $_
} |Export-Csv D:\Users_myfile.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My CSV contain multiple columns. Will this work on that.

Answer (score 0):

- Im-/Export-Csv will inevitably double quote all columns.
- if the encoding is - and should stay - in UTF8, append `-Encoding UTF8` on import and export
- to remove diacritics **only** on specified columns, you'll have to iterate the rows and apply the `Remove-Diacritics` function on just those columns.

Given a sample users.csv:

```
"UserName","LastName"
"Test01ñ","Test01ñ"
"DúSibaagh01","DúSibaagh01"
"ËTheroË01Ë","ËTheroË01Ë"
"DMrçzundaljak01","DMrçzundaljak01"
"PçSchpaglawarz01ç","PçSchpaglawarz01ç"
```

This script:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\12\24\SO_53912246.ps1

function Remove-Diacritics {
  param ([String]$src = [String]::Empty)
   # Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7840951/6811411
   $normalized = $src.Normalize( [Text.NormalizationForm]::FormD )
    $sb = new-object Text.StringBuilder
    $normalized.ToCharArray() | % {
        if( [Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($_) -ne
            [Globalization.UnicodeCategory]::NonSpacingMark ) {
            [void]$sb.Append($_)
        }
    }
    $sb.ToString()
}


$CsvData = Import-csv .\Users.csv -Encoding UTF8

$CsvData | ForEach-Object {
    $_.UserName = Remove-Diacritics $_.UserName
}
$CsvData
$CsvData | Export-Csv .\New_Users.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

will create this output:

```
UserName          LastName
--------          --------
Test01n           Test01ñ
DuSibaagh01       DúSibaagh01
ETheroE01E        ËTheroË01Ë
DMrczundaljak01   DMrçzundaljak01
PcSchpaglawarz01c PçSchpaglawarz01ç
```